# generate separate angular service file for each controller in my api

Tags: swagger-codegen, nswag

this produces a single output containing all the generate clients (angular services)
is it possible generate different output (different service.ts) for each controller

this is my current code

```
        string sUrl = "http://localhost:7325/swagger/v1/swagger.json";
        var document = SwaggerDocument.FromUrlAsync(sUrl).Result;

        var settings = new SwaggerToTypeScriptClientGeneratorSettings
        {

            ClassName = "{controller}Service",
            Template = TypeScriptTemplate.Angular,
            InjectionTokenType = InjectionTokenType.InjectionToken,
            HttpClass = HttpClass.HttpClient,
            GenerateDtoTypes = true,
            BaseUrlTokenName = "API_BASE_URL",
        };

        var generator = new SwaggerToTypeScriptClientGenerator(document, settings);
        var code = generator.GenerateFile();

       //.... 
       //write code to disk
```

installed package: NSwag.CodeGeneration.TypeScript

moreover, is it possible to generate code from an assembly and not from the swagger specification file like NSwagStudio does?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple file output is being worked on at the moment and not available...

Load assembly: https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/WebApiToSwaggerCommand

Comment: Any updates on this?  We need this because we are getting DTO class names like 'DTO1', 'DTO2', etc.  We don't want incremented class names.  Is there another way to do this without putting the services in separate files?

Comment: I think you can provide a custom schema name generator (ISchemaNameGenerator?) to modify the dto names

Comment: I don't want to do that. I'll have to wait for multiple file output, have an nswag config per service or come up with some other solution.